# Rearrange order of columns?

Tags: mysql

I perform a query to make a view like so...

```
SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY created_at, row_id) as id
FROM (
    .... union stuff here
```

But how can I put the column `id` before all the `*` that is selected from the union?

For example, I would like

id | title_from_union | date_from_union | etc

But I cannot put the `row_number()` fnc before the `*` selection as it fails to work.

Comment: *I cannot put the `row_number()` fnc before the `*` selection as it fails to work.* List columns one-by-one, do not use an asterisk.

Comment: That would still fail as the row number fnc relies on created_at and row_id

Comment: A good rule-of-thumb is NEVER use evil `SELECT *`

Comment: *That would still fail as the row number fnc relies on created_at and row_id* ??? Please try firstly...